# Pass Servlet Context Parameter to a Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, controller, context-param

I have a context parameter defined in tomcat server config xml for a given webapp. I want to use this value in a spring mvc controller.

How do I achieve this? How do I make the context param visible to the spring controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject the `ServletContext` in your `@Controller`.

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext context;
```

and use it to retrieve the context parameter

```
context.getInitParameter("param-name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HttpServletRequest parameter in a Controller method.

```
 public String getContextValue(HttpServletRequest httprequest) {

        HttpSession htsession = httprequest.getSession();
          ServletContext servContext = htsession.getServletContext();
            String paramValue = (String)servContext.getInitParameter("paramName");
            return  paramValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

as of 3.0:

```
@Value("#{contextParameters.param-name}")
private String paramName;
```